# Django request showing only the first result

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

The website is about stocking pics of pantsu from ecchi animes, with possible research by color, character's name, anime name,  and type of underwear, without any importance with the order you chose to select any of the criteria.

my Pantsu table have 3 foreignkey -> Color, Type, Girl

my Girl table have a single foreignkey to Anime.

let's assume this :

```
>>> girlList = Girl.objects.all()
>>> girlList
>>> [<Girl: Hanekawa Tsubasa>, <Girl: Hachikuji Mayoi>, <Girl: Hitagi Senjōgahara>]
```

Okay, that's what we wanted, but now, one more thing:

```
>>> Color.objects.filter(pantsu__P_Girl__Girl_Name='Hachikuji Mayoi')    
[Color: White]
```

That's still correct, this girl currently only has one pantsu on my db and it is white. Now this :

```
>>> Color.objects.filter(pantsu__P_Girl__Girl_Name='Hanekawa Tsubasa')    
[Color: Black, Color: Pink]
```

Correct again, but here comes the wrong part, if i want to get the color of all the girls from my db, only having these 2 girls, i would get a result like, [White, Pink, Black], or something like that, but i don't. Look.

```
Color.objects.filter(pantsu__P_Girl=girlList)   
[Color: Pink, Color: Black]
```

I only get results from the first element from my querysets, here i get pink and black because the first element of girlList is Hanekawa Tsubasa, and she match with pink and black.

Why can't i get a result matching every field of the queryset ? Am i missing something ?

Comment: It would be better if you could show the relevant parts of the model instead of a description of them

Comment: Is `girlList` a list of two girl objects? Then you probably need `Color.objects.filter(pantsu__P_Girl__in=girlList)`

Comment: @ilse2005 - `girlList` is the initial queryset of all I think (snippet 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `__in`

```
Color.objects.filter(pantsu__P_Girl__in=girlList)
```

__in accepts a list as input and returns all the records with Girl attribute associated with any of the elements in the list

But as per the question, if girlList is always `Girl.objects.all()`, then you can use:

```
Color.objects.filter(pantsu__P_Girl_isnull=False)
```

or

```
from django.db.models import Q
Color.objects.filter(~Q(pantsu__P_Girl=None))
```

This filters all the color objects that do not have Girl as None

Comment: That's it it works. Thanks a lot, i'll try to find where the doc talks about it and see what else i may have missed.

Answer (score 4):

Ok so as `girllist` is a list you have to use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
Color.objects.filter(pantsu__P_Girl__in=girlList)
```

otherwise it would only use the first entry in the list.

Comment: Whilst correct, I can't help but think theres possibly a more efficient query since girl_list contains every girl

Comment: @Sayse Then I guess we can use `~Q(pantsu__P_Girl=None)` if it is always all the Girl objects

Comment: or without `Q`: `Color.objects.exclude(pantsu__P_Girl=None)`

Comment: @AswinMurugesh - or just `filter(pantsu__P_Girl_isnull=False)` but this assumes that this field can be null which we can't tell, hence why I was asking to see the actual models

Comment: @Sayse If that field cannot be null, then the OP's query makes no sense, since it will always return the entire Color set?